# Is there a formal term for the set of all (geodesic) curves passing through a point?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, differential-topology, geodesic

My context is the spacetime of general relativity.  I want to describe the fact that every spacetime event is the intersection of an infinite number of world-lines.  I found myself reaching for a term that would identify the set of all geodesics passing through a point on a (pseudo-) Riemann manifold.  There is a term *pencil* in projective geometry that has a similar connotation, but I don't believe it could be made to suit my needs.

**Is there a term for the set of all geodesics (or differentiable curves) sharing a common point on a differentiable manifold?**

Comment: Image of rays under exponential map

Comment: That seems to be more of a construction than a designation.  I believe the word I am looking for is "fiber", as in "fiber bundle."

Comment: Geodesic spray.

Comment: I would argue that *fiber* and *geodesic spray* are commonly understood as something quite different from what's being discussed here. I haven't seen a term for this object, but it seems like defining your own term wouldn't be too inconvenient. "Pencil" isn't widely used in Riemannian geometry afaik, so something like *geodesic pencil* could work.

Comment: @Kajelad, I looked up spray, and, alas, its standard definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Geodesic_spray) is indeed not the same (but I would not call it quite different). I also looked up pencil and was reminded that this normally refers to a one-dimensional family of geometric objects. So I don't know any standard formal term. The usual approach is to use mathematical notation, so for example you could say that you will denote the set of all geodesics passing through a point $p$ in the manifold by $\mathcal{G}_p$.

Comment: Yes, I was about to complain that pencil would apply only on a surface. To me, geodesic spray is a global object. I think you just have to define your object yourself. If it's the collection of differentiable curves through a particular point, then you have to also decide whether two curves are different if one is a reparametrization of the other, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin From Einstein's The Meaning of Relativity: "For even if it should appear that the universe of ideas cannot be deduced from experience by logical means, but is, in a sense, a creation of the human mind, without which no science is possible, nevertheless this universe of ideas is just as little independent of the nature of our experiences as clothes are of the form of the human body." 

Since the prototypes of my geodesics are lines measurable with rulers, and worldlines measurable with clocks, I will assume my geodesics exist prior to parameterization.

Comment: I would use the term "the cone of geodesic passing through / emanating from $p$"

Answer (score 1):

In the context of projective spaces, George A. Jennings's *Modern Geometry with Applications* gives:

> A set of lines is **coincident** if all the lines intersect at the same point.

So it seems reasonable to use the term **coincident set of geodesics** to mean a set intersecting at a common point.